# Iterating through 2 matrices in perl

Tags: perl, matrix, syntax

I am trying to write a program that sums two matrices (implemented as a double array) in perl.

I'm sure there's some function that can do it for me, but this is for a homework assignment, so I need to do it myself.

My problem, I'm sure, is in the syntax.  Can you explain what I am doing wrong?

```
sub matrix_add {
  my @matrix1 = $_[0];
  my @matrix2 = $_[1];
  for my $x (0 .. $#matrix1){
    my @line1 = @matrix1[$x];
    my @line2 = @matrix2[$x];
    for my $y (0.. $#line1){
        @line1[$y] += @line2[$y];
    }
  }
  return @matrix1
}
```

I am not getting any errors, but when I print out the array, I'm printing out what I think are references:

```
 ARRAY(0x508a24)ARRAY(0x508b44)
```

Additional info:

I'm declaring the matrices like such:

```
my @matrix = ( 
 [0, 1], 
 [2, 3] 
 );
```

and printing them out them using a double for-each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only pass array reference to function so

```
sub matrix_add {
  my ($matrix1, $matrix2) = @_;
```

and use `@$matrix1`, `@$matrix2` later on in the function.

Comment: Doing that, would my for loop look like `for my $x (0 .. $#$matrix1)`?

Comment: Ah, that worked.  I also had to update the `line` variables so they were references.  Thank you!